# Spring Boot Actuator empty response

Tags: spring-boot, curl, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot app with just below configuration for web security:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
   {
      web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**");
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
   {
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();

      http.csrf().disable();
   }
}
```

application.properites:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,loggers
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

After starting the app I can see in the logs:

```
[ main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver : Exposing 3 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

but then:

```
bash-5.1$ curl -I --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -X "GET" "http://localhost:8083/actuator/health"
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2021 22:26:48 GMT
```

Any thoughts on why it coming back empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because:

```
curl --help all
```

...says:

```
...
 -I, --head               Show document info only
...
```

;)

---

So with:

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -X "GET" "http://localhost:8083/actuator/health"
```

(omitting `-I`) we get the expected:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   171    0   171    0     0  32540      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 42750
{"status":"UP","components":{"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":1991571578880,"free":1684774006784,"threshold":10485760,"exists":true}},"ping":{"status":"UP"}}}
```

Comment: Silly me left it after debugging 401s

Answer (score 0):

Latest spring boot requires two things to be set up:

1- exposing the endpoint in `application.properties` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health
```

You can use a wildcard and expose all endpoints if you want

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

2- enabling info.env in `application.properties`:

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
```

You can set custom info properties:

```
info.app.name=Project
info.app.description=A dummy project
info.app.version=1.0.0
```